# fix colorbar range in basemap python

Tags: python, range, matplotlib-basemap, colorbar

I'm plotting a 2D temperature array over a world map, using `Basemap`. All works fine, except for the colorbar, that I want to fix within a certain range Tmin-Tmax. Unfortunately, `vmin` and `vmax` that I use for matplotlib, here seem not to work and I wasn't able to find the right keywords (if any) used for this purpose. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
map = Basemap(projection='cyl', lat_0 = 57, lon_0 = -135, resolution = RES, area_thresh = 0.1, llcrnrlon=-180., llcrnrlat=-90., urcrnrlon=180., urcrnrlat=90.)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,15),labels=[1,1,0,1])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,15),labels=[1,1,0,1])
map.drawmapboundary()
map.imshow(IR1)
cbar = map.colorbar(location='right', pad="5%")
cbar.set_label('T [Celsius]')
plt.title("temperature")
plt.savefig("temperature.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I give an idea by using **`np.ma.masked`**. Any advice on my work would be appreciate.

I use `an netcdf file` and read the temperature of the whole area. This is similar with your job.

#### Before setting vmin and vmax

```
### Read the file 
wrf_file1 = "wrf_201401.nc"
t_m1 = gdal.Open('NETCDF:"'+wrf_file1+'":T2')
lon = gdal.Open('NETCDF:"'+wrf_file1+'":XLONG')
lat = gdal.Open('NETCDF:"'+wrf_file1+'":XLAT') 

### plot 
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
ax = plt.subplot()
map = basemap(llcrnrlon=xxx,llcrnrlat=xxx,urcrnrlon=xxx,urcrnrlat=xxx)

x, y = map(lon.ReadAsArray()[362], lat.ReadAsArray()[362])

t = t_m1.ReadAsArray()[30,:,:]  ### select one dataframe
cf = map.pcolormesh(x, y,t,cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r,alpha = 0.8) 
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="3%", pad=0.4)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cf, cax=cax)   
plt.show()
```

[image]

The colorbar represent that the temperature were range from 268.5 to 281.

If I want to plot the area which temperature were range from 270 to 275. Here is my solution.

#### Improvement

```
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
ax = plt.subplot()
t = t_m1.ReadAsArray()[30,:,:]
t_mask_1 = np.ma.masked_greater(t,275)
t_mask_2 = np.ma.masked_less(t_mask_1,270)

cf = map.pcolormesh(x, y,t_mask_2,cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r,alpha = 0.8) 
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="3%", pad=0.4)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cf, cax=cax)   

plt.show()
```

[image]